# Migrate from Package base development to Org base development style

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, architecture, lightning-development

Please help me if you have any knowledge regarding the 2 development models right now that Salesforce offered : Org base development model and package development model.
Right now 2 of our developers are using difference development models and its messy. I want to find a way to migrate from package base development model to Org base development model.
Thanks

Comment: Curious why you want to go from packaged based to org based - I would have thought the way forward would be to try and go to packaged based as that seems to be the way of the future?

Comment: Honestly Its so easy to develop and deploy because the true source is the PROD. But then again I'm a beginner so I'm not sure. Whats your opinion about the pros and cons of both I'm very curious . Thanks